# DataTable with multiple possible names for Column

Tags: c#, datatable

Importing data from a Datatable and a column name could have multiple name values, eg. the column might be called "Name" or it could be called "First Name" or "F name"

is there a more efficient way then doing lots of If else's to assign the value of a column

What I have at the moment is

```
   foreach (DataRow item in datatable.Rows)
            {
                var csvEmployee = new CsvEmployee();

                if(datatable.Columns.Contains("Name"))
                    csvEmployee.FirstName = item["Name"].ToString();
                else if (datatable.Columns.Contains("First Name"))
                    csvEmployee.FirstName = item["First Name"].ToString();
                else if (datatable.Columns.Contains("F Name"))
                    csvEmployee.FirstName = item["F Name"].ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Will the datatable always contain that particular column? You could always use an integer column index opposed to the string name to get the column value.

Comment: you could do before the loop `string columnName = item["Name"]?.ToString() ?? 
                          item["First Name"]?.ToString() ?? item["F Name"]?.ToString();` then within the loop do `csvEmployee.FirstName = columnName;`

Comment: @Aominè Thats very neat, I love it. Can you add this as an answer please so I can give it the check mark.

Comment: @CM99 I've updated my answer to take into account the cases where the column name doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `if` / `else if` with the ternary operator although readability is not the best.

do this before the loop:

```
var columns = datatable.Columns;
var columnName = columns.Contains("Name") ? "Name" 
                  : columns.Contains("First Name") ? "First Name" 
                          : columns.Contains("F Name") ? "F Name" : null;
if (columnName == null) return; // assuming the containing method returns void
```

Then within the loop, simply do:

```
csvEmployee.FirstName = item[columnName].ToString();
```

If the containing method doesn't return `void` then don't do `if (columnName == null) return;` as suggested above but rather you can perform a `null` check that only executes the loop when `columnName` is not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Check before the FOR statement what your column is called (by Columns.Contains), assign it to variable and use it in a loop. btw: Try to not use ToString method.

```
        string columnName = null;
        if (datatable.Columns.Contains("Name"))
            columnName = "Name";
        else if (datatable.Columns.Contains("First Name"))
            columnName = "First Name";
        else if (datatable.Columns.Contains("F Name"))
            columnName = "F Name";
       if (columnName == null)
            return;
        foreach (DataRow item in datatable.Rows)
        {
            var csvEmployee = new CsvEmployee();
            csvEmployee.FirstName = item[columnName].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] firstnames = new String[] { "Name", "First Name", "F Name" } //Add more if u want

foreach (string x in firstnames)
    {
        if (datatable.Columns.Contains(x)) csvEmployee.FirstName = item[x];
    }
```